# Firebase observeSingleEvent stays in memory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app uses firebase's observeSingleEventOfType quite a fair bit and I came to realise that my app's memory increase over time. I have commented out all my code except a test button that calls the following function.

```
func loadPostsTest() {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        print(snapshot.value)
    })
}
```

When the program starts, I hit the test button at a fast speed approximately 2,3 times a second and observed the memory graph as shown below. The memory goes up and doesn't come back down after the request. This issue is effecting my app quite a fair bit in the long run as my app's memory would grow from 70mb to 150+mb because of that. Any reason for this?

Note, the short five second rest was me stopping to ensure that all "snapshots" are printed out.

Note 2... When I stop pressing the button, the memory remains at the same level as shown in the "short rest section". Just incase you think that it grows by itself indefinitely

[image: memory image]

-------UPDATE----------

To further confirm the problem, I have create a brand new project with nothing in it but firebase import, a button in the story board with the following code and simulated on my 6s (Simulating on simulator does not appear to have this problem). Image below proves that there is something fishy going on here with firebase as my memory went from 11.1mb to 17.3mb with 303 requests within a minute or so.

[image: memoryleak2]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var count: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func testBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {[weak self] (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        print(self?.count)
        self?.count += 1
    })
}
```

Comment: does this persist when you use `.observeEventOfType`

Comment: Yes it does. However, the result is slightly different. ObserveEventOfType goes up abit slower than ObserveSingleEventOfType.

Comment: Wait this is intriguing , i'll test it out myself...

Comment: Indeed...and it seems to be worst in my actual code where there are multiple variables and functions to grab bits and pieces from my database (As shown in the first image)

Comment: Hey i  even made a whole new app to verify you theory..... Doesn't check out!, Is your snapShot too big in size? Make sure you are removing observers once you are done with them..

Comment: Thanks for the effot Dravidian. That's interesting, what did you do and what was the result? Did you also try ObserveSingleEventOfType as there would be no need to remove observer for that. And my snapshot consists of 8 entries only (some user ID, some ints, one URL linking to amazone s3). I am not storing any files in firebase. Also, did you simulate it on device or computer as simulating on simulator appears to be no problem

Comment: Just a simple app in which DB, has nodes like :- `Users`->`userID`->`userEmail` and tried printing in a **btnAction** . I dont think its a firebase issue...Both on simulator and the device

Comment: Now I am out of ideas.... As that was what I did in the second graph. What Xcode version are you using?

Comment: Xcode 7.3, swift 2.2

Comment: Funny that GoogleMaps also behaves in similar manner...

Comment: I'm dealing with this but when using .childAdded. What would cause this to happen with .childAdded?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is likely only happening because you are running on debug build. My results, after ~128 clicks on device with a debug build:

[image: Increasing memory consumption after ~128 clicks on device.]

As you can see, the vast majority of memory consumption is due to performance tools related to debugging. You can disable this feature if you'd like to confirm it, by editing your scheme:

[image: edit your scheme]

And then disabling backtrace recording:

[image: Disable backtrace recording.]

With it disabled, the same ~128 clicks shows essentially no growth:

[image: No increase in memory consumption after ~128 clicks on device.]

Granted, you may not want to leave that disabled, as you may find it useful for diagnosing crashes and other issues in your debug builds. It shouldn't be a problem in a release build though!

For reference, this was the code I was running:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    private var count: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func testBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let db = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        db.child("posts").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { [weak self] (snap: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            this.count = this.count + 1
            this.label.text = "\(this.count)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! That appears to be the problem for me after trying it. Though if I put it on release mode without disabling the "enable back track recording", the memory still grows. Does that mean release mode still uses back trace recording?

Comment: Well, yes, if you launch it with that enabled. Your users won't be launching it that way though. Try unchecking the "Debug Executable" option. You can still attach the debugger after it launches (Debugger > Attach to Process) to see memory usage...That did the trick for me, as well.

Comment: Basically, it seems if your app is launched with the debugger attached and that option enabled, you will see this issue. With that disabled, or the debugger not attached at launch, the issue goes away. Real users won't experience it, it's purely an artifact of debugging. I don't know if this is expected behavior from Apple's perspective, or an actual bug, either way...It shouldn't affect your actual users.

Comment: Not sure why but whenever I use the instrument I do not have this problem even if the "enable back trace recording" is check. So I do not get your result as shown in your image (Hence I could not use the instrument identify what was wrong). I can only observe this effect when using the inbuilt Xcode memory graph. What do you think about this?

Comment: The difference, I think, is I used the "Profile in Instruments" button to transfer the application to Instruments. If I launch it directly from Instruments, the behavior is as you described. Kind of a peculiar, subtle difference that you wouldn't expect to yield different results, but it seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think this way it will help in xcode too. I have done in my android application.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BLAH_BLAH_STRING");

            // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Do Some Stuff
                    ref.removeEventListener(this);
                    ref = null;

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

*Or in iOS , I guess they have different methods to be used.*

[removeAllObservers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FQuery.html#//api/name/undefined) and [removeObserverWithHandle:](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#fquery_removeObserverWithHandle)

Please try with the given two methods above.

Comment: My project predominately uses observeSingleEventOfType. With that function, I don't believe removing observer are required as there are nothing to remove

Comment: that is also what i am understanding: each time the button is clicked an new event listener is created. or it is automatic restted with the new one?