# Memory leak while reloading the collectionView : Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fill the collectionView with posts.  I have to get the posts, then get some data for the users who posted them.  For some reason it isn't working.

```
DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child("\(self.loggedInUser!.uid)").queryLimitedToLast(30).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { postDictionary in
            if postDictionary.exists() {
                if let snapshots = postDictionary.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    self.posts = [Post]()
                    for snap in snapshots {
                        if let postDict = snap.value as? NSDictionary {
                            for(name, value) in postDict {
                                let interval = postDict.objectForKey("timePosted") as! Double
                                let formattedDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
                                let timeAgo = self.getDate(formattedDate)
                                if name as! String == "postedBy" {
                                    DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(value as! String).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (userDictionary) in
                                        let userDict = userDictionary.value as! NSDictionary
                                        let username = userDict.objectForKey("username")!
                                        let profileThumbUrl = userDict.objectForKey("profileThumbUrl")!
                                        let key = snap.key
                                        let post = Post(postKey: key, dictionary: postDict, username: username as! String, profileThumbUrl: profileThumbUrl as! String, timeAgo: timeAgo)
                                        self.posts.append(post)
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })
```

It works if I perform the reload() right after appending the posts, but there is some sort of memory leak. There isn't a problem in the Post class or filling the collection view, if I use dummy values.  The problem is in this code that I posted.  I think I have an extra loop or something can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean *memory leak*?

Comment: ram usage keeps going up to I think from reloading so much because it's when i put the reload so deep within so many loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fear that reload() is the reason of the memory leak , you can use this hack:-

```
 if name as! String == "postedBy" {
                                DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(value as! String).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (userDictionary) in
                                    let userDict = userDictionary.value as! NSDictionary
                                    let username = userDict.objectForKey("username")!
                                    let profileThumbUrl = userDict.objectForKey("profileThumbUrl")!
                                    let key = snap.key
                                    let post = Post(postKey: key, dictionary: postDict, username: username as! String, profileThumbUrl: profileThumbUrl as! String, timeAgo: timeAgo)
                                    self.posts.append(post)

                                if posts.count == postDictionary.childrenCount{

                                 self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                                    } 
                                })
                            }
```

Then also see this answer :- [Firebase observeSingleEventOfType stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39100825/6297658)

Comment: Yes, it was running reloadData a lot of times and for some reason causing it to use like 3x the memory (if using 30 posts) if i let it load like 120 posts it just kept going up until it crashes.  This was perfect.  I have been trying to figure it out all day and I was just trying to do what you did there but couldn't figure out how to get postDictionary count lol.